# Changing NSData byte order to little endian

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, endianness

I am trying to figure out the best way to change the byte order of my NSData object that I have.

This is how I create it

```
NSData *pillowData = [manufData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 4)];
```

This is the output of pillowData

```
41543138
```

This is what i want pillowData to be after conversion.

```
38315441
```

Essentially converting to little endian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    NSData *manufData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"12345AT18" length:9];
    NSMutableData *pillowData = [[manufData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 4)] mutableCopy];
    uint32_t *bytes = pillowData.mutableBytes;
    *bytes = CFSwapInt32(*bytes);
    NSLog(@"%@", pillowData);
```

Output:

```
2018-01-25 15:52:39.067805-0600 test[23520:1338453] <38315441>
```

Note that this doesn't change the contents of `manufData`. It only changes the copy of the bytes in `pillowData`.

Answer (score 4):

NSData has no concept of endianness, it is a simple sequence of bytes. If you need to impose a certain order of those bytes, you'll have to roll your own code for that.

That said, Core Foundation has a bunch of helper methods for this, eg. `CFSwapInt32()` and many others, all declared in `CFByteOrder.h`, which may be helpful.